# Processing Of Logback's Compressed Rolled-Over Files

Tags: java, synchronization, logback

I have LogBack configured so that it rolls over every hour creating a file such as log.20150806-10.log.zip.

In a special thread I would like to regularly check if there are new rolled-over files and if so, upload them somewhere and then delete them.

Looking at the source of of LogBack's [Compressor.java](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/master/logback-core/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/core/rolling/helper/Compressor.java), it just opens the target zip file, starts writing to it and closes it.

I think my thread might discover the file before the Compressor completes writing to it.

This would probably not be a problem if I were not using compression, because then there's just file renaming.

How can I synchronize this?

Both the appender and the processing thread run in the same JVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I dealt with this problem.

- I stopped using the compression feature of LogBack. This way, LogBack creates the new rolled over files by renaming the original log file. Renaming of files is atomic on most platforms.
- In a separate thread, I am checking for the new files to appear in the directory. Once I see a new file, I can process it immediatelly.
- I am doing the ZIP compression myself.